# Exclude from a select more than 2101 records with laravel sql query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using something like this:

```
$scanned = DB::table("Persons")
        ->whereNotIn("Person_Id", $exclude)
        ->get();
```

The problem is $exclude has more than 2101 records, and I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 2101.  SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.
```

Is there a way around? how can I solve this?

Comment: Can the list of numbers be built by querying the database? If so, you should be able to make do this query with a subselect or an outer join.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Could you please help me to understand how would your solution be?

Comment: If (for example) you can build the list of ids with the query `SELECT person_id FROM exclude_table` then you can provide that query as the `NOT IN` parameter, like `SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM exclude_table)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following tables as an example.

```
TABLE persons
  id
  name

TABLE tags
  id
  person_id
  tag
```

Suppose I wanted persons who did not have certain tags. I could do this as follows:

```
$exclude = DB::table('tags')->where('tag', 'some_tag')->pluck('person_id');
```

then

```
DB::table('persons')->whereNotIn($exclude)->get();
```

The above might have the same problem as your code if there a lot of data. Instead I would do it as a join.

```
$scanned = DB::table('persons')->join('tags')->where('tag', '!=', 'some_tag')->distinct('persons.id')->get();
```